# Distributing c++ software macOS. Static, Dynamic, Installers

Tags: c++

My project uses OpenCV installed via homebrew

- I've tried static linking via my cmakelists, but it doesn't seem to work and still looks for the dylibs.
- I've tried to build my own OpenCV but I can't get the project to link to it.

The project is a terminal utility, how can I package it and the dylibs so that they can be installed on a client system? Where the user doesn't have Homebrew/OpenCV installed or any knowledge and desire to do it manually.

---

I've managed to get self built openCV linking with. I think previously there were several versions floating around on my system where I have been trying to get this to work. I cleaned them all up and started from the beginning.

- add opencv to project libs subfolder
- configure in cmake gui and generate unix make files. Some tinkering here, had to turn zlib off and eigen otherwise i'd get build errors later down the line.
- run make install
- updated project cmake as below

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

if(APPLE)
    set (CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "11" CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version" FORCE)
    set (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64" CACHE STRING "Architectures" FORCE)
    set (CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET[arch=arm64] "11.0" CACHE STRING "arm 64 minimum deployment target" FORCE)
endif()


project(watermark)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(libs/cargs)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_executable(watermark main.cpp watermark.h watermark.cpp)
target_link_libraries(watermark LINK_PUBLIC cargs ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

The release binary is around 4MB so seems to be working.

However when trying to run on client systems I now get:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTTNSt3__114basic_ifstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/howardcolin/Desktop/./watermark
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
```

Is there anything else to add to the linker section for a fully statically linked independent binary that will run on any MacOS11+

When adding this target to cmake I get linker warnings that OpenCV was built for MacOS 12.5, so probs need to rebuild openCV again...

Comment: Doesn't CPack have some support for macOS? I am not a macOS developer but I found this: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/productbuild.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/productbuild.html)

Comment: There is also this: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/bundle.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/bundle.html)

Comment: what problem did you have when using your own copy of OpenCV? Homebrew is only really for local use, its not designed as a source of redistributable libraries

Comment: @AlanBirtles I cloned the repo to the a `/libs` folder in my project and configured with cmake gui, ran make to build. I just couldn't get my project to link to the files `.a` files. Errors were couldn't find `opencv.hpp` or `opencv_modules.hpp`

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you tried, sounds more like include errors than link errors

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ive updated with how I managed to get it working so far. 
Im still learning how to manage external deps and build systems for release, it seems to be a bit of minefield. Is there a better way to manage this than what I am doing at the moment.

Comment: https://conan.io/

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks for the suggestion. followed along with the initial tutorial for this on their website and it failed. I tired some other libs I use regularly and they also failed. Seems every package has some dependency that is ` WARN: Package binary is corrupted, removing: 238a93dc813ca1550968399f1f8925565feeff8e`

Comment: raise a bug report if you find something broken